# Adding commas after imported numerical values

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I need the values from a CSV to have a comma after each individual value as well at the end of each row/array.

I have used `tolist()` before having these changes. The conversion of numerical values to strings is not wanted.

The code below is what I currently have.

```
import numpy as np
dataset = open("Dataset.csv")
next(dataset)  # Skips first line of dataset
games = np.loadtxt(dataset, delimiter=",")
dataset.close()
print(games)
```

This is what the code outputs:

```
[[ 0.228  0.5    0.685  0.378  0.439  0.183  0.387  0.25   0.169]
 [ 0.206  0.125  0.686  0.069  0.131  0.778  2.71   0.75  -0.092]]
```

I am looking for the code to output this:

```
[[0.228,0.5  ,0.685,0.378,0.439,0.183,0.387,0.25 ,0.169],
 [0.206,0.125 ,0.686 ,0.069 ,0.131,0.778 ,2.71 ,0.75 ,-0.092]
```

Comment: What do you mean by not wanting the numerical values to be changed to strings? Numerical values are numbers; you cannot add arbitrary characters to the end of them (like a comma). You need strings for that. Also, if you are trying to output in CSV format, there are tried and tested functions for that.

Comment: The output from this is an array of floats. If you want to see the commas, you can do `print(repr(games))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically set any formatter you desire to print your output with via `np.set_print_optiones` (this does not change your original array type and only change the printing format, which I think is what you are looking for). I think this is what you are looking for, but if it is not, you can define your desirable format through this:

```
#be mindful this creates comma after each float number including the last number in sub-arrays
float_formatter = "{:},".format 
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
print(games)
```

output:

```
[[0.228, 0.5, 0.685, 0.378, 0.439, 0.183, 0.387, 0.25, 0.169,]
 [0.206, 0.125, 0.686, 0.069, 0.131, 0.778, 2.71, 0.75, -0.092,]]
```

and your datatype is float:

```
print(games.dtype)

float64
```

A better option mentioned by @David Buck in comments is to use `repr`

print(repr(games))

output:

```
array([[ 0.228,  0.5  ,  0.685,  0.378,  0.439,  0.183,  0.387,  0.25 ,
         0.169],
       [ 0.206,  0.125,  0.686,  0.069,  0.131,  0.778,  2.71 ,  0.75 ,
        -0.092 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand what python object you have, and what the commas, or lack, means.

With `loadtxt` you created a numpy array.  A simpler way of doing the same:

```
In [212]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)
```

The `repr` display for an array is:

```
In [213]: arr                                                                            
Out[213]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The `str` dislay omits the commas.  That's intentional, helping to distinguish an array from a list:

```
In [214]: print(arr)                                                                     
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]]
In [215]: type(arr)                                                                      
Out[215]: numpy.ndarray
```

The print display of a list has commas:

```
In [216]: print(arr.tolist())                                                            
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

The distinction between a list (or list of lists) and an array is important.  Whether the display uses commas or not is superficial.